# Prove or disprove that Q[√2] is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $R = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2]$ = {$\alpha + \beta\sqrt2 \;|\; \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Q}$} and $z = a + b\sqrt2$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$

1. Prove or disprove R is a field.
2. Prove $(a + b\sqrt2)(a - b\sqrt2) \neq0$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$
3. Prove that $(a+b\sqrt2) \in U(R)$

My attempt:
1.  Working on it...

2. $(a + b\sqrt2)(a - b\sqrt2) = a^2 - (\sqrt2)^2b^2$. Since $\sqrt2$ is not a rational number, $a^2 - 2b^2 \neq 0$
3. Confused. I know I need to show  $(a + b\sqrt2)(a - b\sqrt2)$ = 1 to be in $U(R)$ but not exactly sure how to proceed.

Comment: (1) answers (3) since $\;R\;$ is a field $\;\implies\;$ every non-zero element in it is a unit. BTW, in (3) is missing the condition $\;ab\neq0\;$

Comment: Timbuc: $\left(a,b\right) \neq \left(0,0\right)$, not $ab \neq 0$.

Comment: In view of the fact that you've shown in (2) that $(a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})$ is *not* in general equal to 1, perhaps you should stop trying to show the opposite in (3).

Comment: @ OP: Your proof of (2) is correct. (3) would answer (1). Remains to do (3). Say you want to divide $1$ by $a + b\sqrt 2$ and write the result in the form $c + d\sqrt 2$; do you know some tricks (from school maybe) how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2}-\frac{b}{a^2-2b^2}\sqrt{2}=(a+b\sqrt{2})^{-1}$$ whenever $a$ and $b$ are not simultaneously $0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: (1) Let $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$ and $J = \{f(x) \in R[x] ; f(\alpha) = 0\}$

$$\frac{ R[x]}{J} \simeq  R[\alpha]$$

$J$ is maximal then $ \frac{R[x]}{J}$ is a field.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is irrelevant here. :)

Comment: I thought I'd seen $\mathbb R$.