# Prove that $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2) = \{\alpha+\beta\sqrt2|\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Tags: field-theory

So I have only found that this is a given by definition, but i'm being asked to prove it, my idea was to prove the opposite and get a contradiction but I'm not sure:

Suppose $\exists x\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)|x\neq \alpha+\beta\sqrt2$ with $\alpha$,$\beta \in \mathbb{Q}$

for $x=\alpha$  contradiction since $ x\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$

for $x=\beta\sqrt2$, contradiction since it's the same as having $\alpha =0$, therefore it's in the form of $\alpha+\beta\sqrt2$ .

Therefore  $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2) = \{\alpha+\beta\sqrt2|\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Is this prove correct?

Edit:
This comes because we are studying Fields, so we were asked to prove that $\left\langle \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2),+,\times \right\rangle$ is a Field, but before that, we need to prove that every element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ is of the form $\alpha+\beta\sqrt2$

Comment: I think that is usually the definition, so if you are asked to prove that then it should say what you are supposed to assume when you prove it.

Comment: Some people *define* $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}):=\{a+b\sqrt{2}\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$ in which case there is nothing to prove. Assuming that there *is* something to prove here, I take that you do *not* define $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ as above. How do *you* define it?

Comment: You need to provide a definition. You can take $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ to be the subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ generated by $\sqrt{2}$, for example; then there is something to prove.

Comment: Some people define $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ as the smallest subfield of $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ containing both the whole $\mathbb Q$ and also containing $\sqrt{2}$. Does this ring any bells? There are other (increasingly abstract) definitions in algebra that build upon that definition, for example.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129105/prove-or-disprove-that-q√2-is-a-field?rq=1) is a proof that $\{ a+b\sqrt{2}\mid a,b\in \Bbb Q\}$ is indeed a *field*.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$\Bbb Q(\sqrt2) \cong \Bbb Q[x]/(x^2-2)$.  The evaluation homomorphism $h(p(x))=p(\sqrt2) $ induces an isomorphism.

The result follows because the result of division by $x^2-2$ is an at most linear polynomial.

---

Other details are that $x^2-2$ is irreducible,  hence the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt2$.  $(x^2-2)$ is thus a maximal ideal.  It's also the kernel of $h$.  An integral domain modulo a maximal ideal is a field.

Answer (score 1):

By definition we have $$\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]=\{a+b\sqrt 2\mid a,b\in\Bbb Q\}$$

However $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is smallest the field containing $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$, in other words, you have to study division of elements in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$. If you manage to show that $$\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt 2}$$ is on the form $\alpha+\beta\sqrt 2$, then you will be done. For a hint, try to make the denominator an integer.

Comment: This answer assumes that the OP defines $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ in a certain way. I would wait for them to clarify the question before providing the answer. We don't even know if they know what a "field" is.

Comment: I would think that similarly (often/sometimes?) $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt2]$ is *defined* to be the smallest subring of $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$ (or any other fitting ring) containing $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt2$.

Comment: This comes because we are studying Fields, so we were asked to prove that $\left\langle \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2),+,\times \right\rangle$ is a Field, but before that, we need to prove that every element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ is of the form $\alpha+\beta\sqrt2$, so if I prove what you're saying have I done that?

Comment: @Hector how is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ defined for you?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout There was no definition, I was just asked to prove it has that form, and then prove it's a field.